# IntelliJ IDEA's counterpart to Eclipse's Quick Diff

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

I just moved to IntelliJ IDEA after spending years working in Eclipse. Eclipse has "Quick Diff" option that allows me to choose color for each type of modification (new line added, line deleted and line modified). It compares my local changes and Git / SVN / CVS code, depending on what you choose. Does IntelliJ has this option or some plugin that does the same thing?

I'm sorry if this question has already been asked before. I tried to find it on IntelliJ's page, on Google and Stack-overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ will by default diff with the VCS that's set up for the project/module, but you can also diff two files by right-clicking on one of them and selecting `Compare With...`.

To change the colors go to **Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > Diff & Merge**. The `important` color is the highlighting of the line in the diff view, the `Error stripe mark` color is the color shown in the gutter.

[image: settings page]